# While creating a form using salesforce visual force pages and saving the data, it results in an error

Tags: salesforce

While creating a form using salesforce visual force pages and saving the data, it results in the following error:

> Attempt to de-reference a null object
> Error is in expression '{!save}' in component apex:commandButton in page contract_object: Class.ContractController.save: line 7, column 1
>
> An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

My apex code is as follows:

```
<apex:page Controller="ContractController" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Contract Form">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.First_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Last_Name__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Phone_Number__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Address__c}" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!conObj.Email__c}" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The controller is as follows:

```
public with sharing class ContractController {
    public Contract__c conObj {get; set;}
    public void newContract() {
        conObj = new Contract__c();
    }
    public void save() {
        insert conObj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `newContract()` is not called anywhere.

You can make it run as constructor (special function with name same as class name)

```
public ContractController () {
    conObj = new Contract__c();
}
```

If you haven't used constructors before you'll have hard time.

Or a slightly "pro" way would be to read up about "Standard Controller" and [extension classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm) (that's a change mostly in apex side of stuff but also in 1st line of your VF)